# Differential Geometry: Map Vs Trace

Tags: differential-geometry

I have started reading a book on the subject and the author writes:

"one should carefully distinguish a parametrized curve, which is a map, from its trace, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$"

What does he mean?

If we look at $\alpha(t)=cost,sint$ the map is the function whereas the trace is a "graph" in a the shape of a circle?

Comment: The key point is that the same trace can be traversed with different velocities.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia for example in my example a "faster"  trace will be $a(t)=cos(5t),sin(5t)$?

Comment: The answer to your last question is "yes". Think of a car going around a track. The position of the car as a function of the parameter time is the parameterized curve. The trace is the track.

Comment: A map gives you explicit directions on how to traverse the trace: you lose information by forgetting the map and just remembering the trace.

Comment: @gbox But this change of parametrization can be "ill". For instance, $\alpha(t)=(\cos t^2,\sin t^2)$ gives null spped at $t=0$ so a singular point arises. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve#Parametric_curves